# write file contents to jsp

Tags: java, file, jsp, jsp-tags

I would like to write the contents of a (text) file to a JSP. I will do this from within a tag
What is the best way to grab the file contents and write to the object produced by a call to "pageContext.getOut()" from within my tag?

I ask as I am unsure of the various readers, writers and buffers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [apache commons-io library](http://commons.apache.org/io/). It has a utility method to get File contents as a String:

```
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("somefile.txt"));
```

**Caution** - This convenient method is only for use with smallish files. If the file is large, a *streaming* approach is needed (where you write bytes to the output stream as you read them from the file)

Comment: That is true if the file is large - I have edited the answer to add cautionary note. +1 Good comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try Commons-IO: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html

And one of it's `copy()` methods.

```
IOUtils.copy( 
   new FileInputStream( new File(...) ), 
   pageContext.getResponse().getOutputStream() 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use scriptlets you might create a functions class similar to the JSTL functions which provides a static method to do that. Then use an expression to read the file.

Example:

```
package your.pkg

public class FileAccess {
  public static String readTxtFile( String filename )  {
     return FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(filename)); //used Bohemian's suggestion here :)
  }
}
```

In your taglib file you'd have this entry:

```
<function>
  <name>readTxtFile</name>
  <function-class>
    your.pkg.FileAccess 
  </function-class>
  <function-signature>
    java.lang.String readTxtFile( java.lang.String )
  </function-signature>
</function>
```

And finally in your JSP:

```
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="your taglib uri" %>

${f:readTxtFile( 'path/to/myfile.txt' )} //reads the file and writes the return value to the JSP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a;

```
<jsp:include page="myfile.txt">
```

No readers/writers/buffers etc required.

Comment: That would only work if the file is located in the same web project/WEB-INF, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thomas, you are correct. As the file is not located in the project. This option is not viable